# Карта под андроид

Tags: java, android, карты

Есть готовое приложение, которое уже запущено и написано на *Java*. Несколько классов и *xml* файлов написано в *Android Studio*, никаких дополнительных библиотек, все стандартные.

Сейчас необходимо в приложение добавить карту. Карта стран с реальными границами.

Главные функции карты:

1. Возможность выделять страны, как одну, так и несколько десятков.
2. Возможность изменять цвет территорий стран (при нажатии и программно в `onCreate`).
3. Добавлять на карту графические объекты (иконки).
4. Считывание нажатий/кликов с карты, определение страны, на которую кликнули.
5. Решение не должно зависеть от доступа к интернету.

Думаю прикрутить *LibGDX*. Может у кого-то есть опыт решения подобных задач? Можете скинуть ссылки на пример или в какую сторону копать?

Пример реализованных карт на других приложениях:

[первый](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=age.of.civilizations.jakowski)

[второй](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.game.drisk)

Comment: Сразу 5 вопросов? Каждому отдельно создайте вопросы!

Comment: @Omuradil Внимательно прочитайте, прежде чем писать "Сразу 5 вопросов?". Это функции, которыми должна обладать платформа. Вы вообще не читаете детали вопроса, раз пишите такие сообщения?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам лучше по одному искать...

Comment: @Omuradil как вы себе это представляете? Я настоятельно рекомендую вам прочитать мой вопрос. Мне необходимо, чтобы решение могло удовлетворить 5 функций.

Comment: Как решили задачу? У меня похожая сейчас. Надо отображать собственную карту и измерять расстояния.